# Xcode Storyboard shows white Controller (blank)

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xib

I have a problem with my storyboard in Xcode.

9 of 15 View-Controllers in my Storyboard are displayed blank - only the three icons on the top are displayed.

I use a Navigation-Controller to manage my 15 Controllers.

Reboot and cleaning the project not help.

[image: Storyboard-Error-Image]

Comment: may be sizeclasses issue

Comment: Do you use size classes? Which Xcode version did you use to create project and which Xcode do you use now?

Comment: The simulated size of my View-Controllers are fixed under size inspector. My XCode version is: 8.2.1 (8C1002). Zooming for display errors also not helped.

Comment: vary for traits select a top resolution device sometimes it may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but varying the sizes also not helped.

Comment: close Xcode, restart your laptop and it should be working

Answer (score 0):

[image: May be issue with Size classes]

The following table gives an overview of the available Size Classes.

- **Device Orientation** *Vertical Size Class/Horizontal Size Class*
- **iPad Portrait**        Regular               /  Regular
- **iPad Landscape**       Regular          /      Regular
- **iPhone Portrait**      Regular       /          Compact
- **iPhone Landscape**     Compact       /          Compact

Comment: Thank you - but resizing the View-Controller does also not help. Anything worked great but today I opened the storyboard an many View-Controllers displayed no content.